# Unable to show the plot when concatenating two json objects

Tags: dc.js

I am trying to extend [it](https://blockbuilder.org/gordonwoodhull/707fbf6e387dd63158fab2652d740b6a) to work on the concatenated dataset. Initially I was working for the cumulative cases of states but now I have added the daily cases also. ( see `Line 121-Line 192`)

Current work => https://blockbuilder.org/ninjakx/76e7ddf821509e308b741fead46f8bb4

So my data look like this now:

[image]

Initially It was like this:

[image]

You can see there are not a major difference. Since 31st jan to 13th march data for states were missing so I added statewise data by assigning cases to zero. 
also previously in my chart my data was `var data = json_data.data.history;` but in this case I will pass the `data` directly.

Now When I use the same script(creating the chart) I get this error:

```
error TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'state' of 'undefined' as it is undefined.
    at untitled1.html:213
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at cases_bar_d.group.reduce.v.statewise.forEach.state.state (untitled1.html:213)
    at resetMany (crossfilter.js:1135)
    at all (crossfilter.js:1159)
    at Object.top (crossfilter.js:1165)
    at stateline_chart (untitled1.html:231)
    at untitled1.html:191
```

I can see in `Line 215` that `p[state]` is undefined but it was undefined for former work also. So how did that work for the previous work but not for this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were some 1 state was missing for a day: `2020-05-17`

As I was using loop -> `range(37)` so it was giving me undefined property 
`data_add['statewise'][st].state` -> became undefined.

I just had to use loop `range(data_add['statewise'].length)` not `range(37)`